# Unable to compile Eclipse PAHO MQTT Client project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am following the following steps:

1. git clone http://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/paho/org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java.git
2. cd org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java.git
3. mvn package -DskipTests

This step result in:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: org.eclipse.paho:java-parent

Reason: Cannot find layout implementation corresponding to: 'p2' for remote repository with id: 'eclipse-kepler'. for project org.eclipse.paho:java-parent


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.reactor.MavenExecutionException: Cannot find layout implementation corresponding to: 'p2' for remote repository with id: 'eclipse-kepler'. for project org.eclipse.paho:java-parent
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjects(DefaultMaven.java:404)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Cannot find layout implementation corresponding to: 'p2' for remote repository with id: 'eclipse-kepler'. for project org.eclipse.paho:java-parent
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildArtifactRepositories(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:949)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.assembleLineage(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1206)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildInternal(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:823)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromSourceFileInternal(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:508)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.build(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProject(DefaultMaven.java:604)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:487)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjects(DefaultMaven.java:391)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.InvalidRepositoryException: Cannot find layout implementation corresponding to: 'p2' for remote repository with id: 'eclipse-kepler'.
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectUtils.getRepositoryLayout(ProjectUtils.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectUtils.buildArtifactRepository(ProjectUtils.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectUtils.buildArtifactRepositories(ProjectUtils.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildArtifactRepositories(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:942)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: Component descriptor cannot be found in the component repository: org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.layout.ArtifactRepositoryLayoutp2.
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:323)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:440)
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectUtils.getRepositoryLayout(ProjectUtils.java:153)
    ... 22 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: < 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Nov 22 11:37:37 CET 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 2M/136M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If remove 'eclipse-kepler' reposiroty in pom.xml get other type of errors.

```
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Reactor build order: 
[INFO]   Eclipse Paho
[INFO]   Unnamed - org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:eclipse-plugin:1.0.1
[INFO]   Unnamed - org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.test:jar:1.0.1
[INFO]   Unnamed - org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.eclipse.feature:eclipse-feature:1.0.1
[INFO]   Unnamed - org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.eclipse.view:eclipse-plugin:1.0.1
[INFO]   Paho P2 Repository
[INFO]   Unnamed - org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.utility:jar:1.0.1
[INFO]   Unnamed - org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.ui:pom:1.0.1
[INFO]   Unnamed - org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.ui.core:eclipse-plugin:1.0.1
[INFO]   Unnamed - org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.ui.app:eclipse-repository:1.0.1
[INFO]   Unnamed - org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.ui.plugin:pom:1.0.1
[INFO]   Eclipse Paho - MQTT Android Service
[INFO]   Unnamed - org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:jar:1.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Eclipse Paho
[INFO]    task-segment: [package]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [site:attach-descriptor {execution: default-attach-descriptor}]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:eclipse-plugin:1.0.1
[INFO]    task-segment: [package]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Internal error in the plugin manager executing goal 'org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:0.20.0:build-qualifier': Unable to find the mojo 'build-qualifier' (or one of its required components) in the plugin 'org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin'
Component descriptor cannot be found in the component repository: org.codehaus.plexus.logging.Logger.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Internal error in the plugin manager executing goal 'org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:0.20.0:build-qualifier': Unable to find the mojo 'build-qualifier' (or one of its required components) in the plugin 'org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin'
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:698)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginManagerException: Unable to find the mojo 'build-qualifier' (or one of its required components) in the plugin 'org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin'
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:674)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:468)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: Unable to lookup component 'org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojoorg.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:0.20.0:build-qualifier', it could not be started
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:339)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:440)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:652)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLifecycleException: Error starting component
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.AbstractComponentManager.startComponentLifecycle(AbstractComponentManager.java:109)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.AbstractComponentManager.createComponentInstance(AbstractComponentManager.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.PerLookupComponentManager.getComponent(PerLookupComponentManager.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:331)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.personality.plexus.lifecycle.phase.PhaseExecutionException: Error composing component
    at org.codehaus.plexus.personality.plexus.lifecycle.phase.CompositionPhase.execute(CompositionPhase.java:33)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleHandler.start(AbstractLifecycleHandler.java:101)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.AbstractComponentManager.startComponentLifecycle(AbstractComponentManager.java:105)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.CompositionException: Composition failed of field projectTypes in object of type org.eclipse.tycho.buildversion.BuildQualifierMojo because the requirement ComponentRequirement{role='org.eclipse.tycho.core.TychoProject', roleHint='null', fieldName='projectTypes'} was missing
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.FieldComponentComposer.assignRequirementToField(FieldComponentComposer.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.FieldComponentComposer.assembleComponent(FieldComponentComposer.java:73)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.DefaultComponentComposerManager.assembleComponent(DefaultComponentComposerManager.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.composeComponent(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:1486)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.personality.plexus.lifecycle.phase.CompositionPhase.execute(CompositionPhase.java:29)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: Unable to lookup component 'org.eclipse.tycho.core.TychoProjecteclipse-test-plugin', it could not be started
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:339)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:440)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookupMap(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:390)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.FieldComponentComposer.assignRequirementToField(FieldComponentComposer.java:103)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLifecycleException: Error starting component
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.AbstractComponentManager.startComponentLifecycle(AbstractComponentManager.java:109)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.AbstractComponentManager.createComponentInstance(AbstractComponentManager.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.ClassicSingletonComponentManager.getComponent(ClassicSingletonComponentManager.java:92)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:331)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.personality.plexus.lifecycle.phase.PhaseExecutionException: Error composing component
    at org.codehaus.plexus.personality.plexus.lifecycle.phase.CompositionPhase.execute(CompositionPhase.java:33)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleHandler.start(AbstractLifecycleHandler.java:101)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.AbstractComponentManager.startComponentLifecycle(AbstractComponentManager.java:105)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.CompositionException: Composition failed of field resolver in object of type org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.OsgiTestBundleProject because the requirement ComponentRequirement{role='org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.EquinoxResolver', roleHint='null', fieldName='resolver'} was missing
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.FieldComponentComposer.assignRequirementToField(FieldComponentComposer.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.FieldComponentComposer.assembleComponent(FieldComponentComposer.java:73)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.DefaultComponentComposerManager.assembleComponent(DefaultComponentComposerManager.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.composeComponent(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:1486)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.personality.plexus.lifecycle.phase.CompositionPhase.execute(CompositionPhase.java:29)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: Unable to lookup component 'org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.EquinoxResolver', it could not be started
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:339)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.FieldComponentComposer.assignRequirementToField(FieldComponentComposer.java:129)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLifecycleException: Error starting component
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.AbstractComponentManager.startComponentLifecycle(AbstractComponentManager.java:109)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.AbstractComponentManager.createComponentInstance(AbstractComponentManager.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.ClassicSingletonComponentManager.getComponent(ClassicSingletonComponentManager.java:92)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:331)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.personality.plexus.lifecycle.phase.PhaseExecutionException: Error composing component
    at org.codehaus.plexus.personality.plexus.lifecycle.phase.CompositionPhase.execute(CompositionPhase.java:33)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleHandler.start(AbstractLifecycleHandler.java:101)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.AbstractComponentManager.startComponentLifecycle(AbstractComponentManager.java:105)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.CompositionException: Composition failed of field logger in object of type org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.EquinoxResolver because the requirement ComponentRequirement{role='org.codehaus.plexus.logging.Logger', roleHint='null', fieldName='logger'} was missing
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.FieldComponentComposer.assignRequirementToField(FieldComponentComposer.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.FieldComponentComposer.assembleComponent(FieldComponentComposer.java:73)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.DefaultComponentComposerManager.assembleComponent(DefaultComponentComposerManager.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.composeComponent(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:1486)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.personality.plexus.lifecycle.phase.CompositionPhase.execute(CompositionPhase.java:29)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: Component descriptor cannot be found in the component repository: org.codehaus.plexus.logging.Logger.
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:323)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:312)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.FieldComponentComposer.assignRequirementToField(FieldComponentComposer.java:129)
    ... 52 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Nov 22 11:45:51 CET 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/265M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to upgrade maven from 2.x to 3.x.

Comment: Yes @Que, that was the answer, I got it from a long time but forgot update the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Note that on Ubuntu, the 'maven' package is newer than the 'maven2' package. The following commands fixed it for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove maven2
sudo apt-get install maven
```